# Apply SQL function to field queried by LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I need to get records set from database using LINQ, but one of the fields that I query need to be transformed by SQL function. As I understand LINQ query:

```
var records = context.Geometries
            .Where(x => x.Name == "SomeName")
            .ToList();
```

returns some SQL string like this:

```
select Id, Name, Shape from MyGeometries where Name = 'SomeName'
```

if MyGeometry class looks like:

```
public class MyGeometry
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "geometry")]
    public Geometry Shape { get; set; }
}
```

Is there some LINQ extension method to apply SQL function to one of the fields? It may be look like:

```
var records = context.MyGeometries
            .ApplySql(x => x.Shape, "ST_Transform", param1, param2...)
            .Where(x => x.Name == "SomeName")
            .ToList();
```

Then generated SQL must be like this:

```
select Id, Name, ST_Transform(Shape, param1, param2...) from MyGeometries where Name = 'SomeName'
```

Or is there any attribute applied to model property with function name that will be called always, when I query it in LINQ? Something like this:

```
public class MyGeometry
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "geometry")]
    [ApplySql("ST_Transform", param1, param2...)]
    public Geometry Shape { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You are using Entity where there is a mapping between the database tables and classes that were generated by Entity (your context class model).  Linq for these classes work the same as linq with any other classes.  So no extension/attribute is needed.

Comment: The only solution that I found is to use attribute DbFunction with the SQL function name and parameters with throw new NotImplementedException(); inside, but all examples use this function with WHERE statement, but I need convert one of the field in SELECT
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-2.0#database-scalar-function-mapping

Comment: The requirements to this answer are:
1. ST_Transform should be called on database server side because it doesn't have the analogue C# function.
2. It should be performed before the records become in memory.

Comment: You want to execute a stored procedure.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/how-to-execute-a-parameterized-stored-procedure-using-entitycommand

Comment: Then create a method in the class (or an interface).  You can call helper methods from linq like any other code : .ApplySql(x => ST_Transform(x.shape, param1, param2...))

Comment: It would be better use LINQ instead of ADO, because there are already many different LINQ queries to models with different properties, but transform function must be performed to one of them. The best way would be use some attribute to necessary field with procedure name to perform. Or is there a way to create computed field, that will not be the part of model? For example: select Id, Name, Shape, ST_Transform(Shape, 59002) as TransformedShape, where Id, Name, Shape and TransformedShape are properties of model, but TransformedShape is not mapped (it is just computed)

Comment: I know about extensions, but how it will be implemented if ST_Transform function exists only on database side as SQL function? It has no implementation in C# code

Comment: You can't have your cake and have you pie too.  Either you need to use a stored procedure and execute the code on the server; or create the method in c# and execute the code on the client.  You can't have both.   The stored procedure in a Command Text is a string.  So you can create a c# method that accepts a string and parameters and then calls the stored procedure.